# How do I change the background color of a page in Jade?

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

I'm very new to jade and I'm trying to build pages for a website using it. I have most of the functionality of my site working but now it's important for the users that I "beautify" it. One issue for instance is just changing the background color of my page. Right now I'm getting an error that says "unexpected text".

My current code is as follows:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title

        style
            body {
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 13px;
                background: #464646
            }
    body
    h1 Welcome!
    h2 Please select your bus

    div Bus #27
    form(name="bus27", action="/bus27", method="get")
        input(type="submit", value="Elementary Bus 27")
```

I'm trying to make the background yellow. Also what are other common features that can be changed/assigned (font size, color) and how do you template/better organize titles and forms on my page?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I don't know Jade but it looks like you're just missing a semi-colon after the value for background.

Comment: You also need a . after your style tag, eg: `style.`   for it to compile properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a period after the style tag:

```
style.
    body {
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: #464646;
    }
```

The period tells jade that everything nested within should be considered a text string to be inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Thank you! Second question, how do I arrange text/images horizontally in a jade file (tempting and such)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you elaborate a bit?